# Ruby - Query with multiple subqueries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I write a where condition query using ruby for the following SQL statement? I believe we need to define a `belongs_to` on the `service_tempaltes` model before we can query other tables?

```
select * from service_templates where miq_group_id IN ( SELECT miq_group_id from entitlements where miq_user_role_id IN (SELECT id from miq_user_roles where settings is NULL) );
```

`service_templates` by default cannot join with other tables unless we define a `belongs_to` which I'm not sure if necessary. But I want to write a where condition in the scope section based on the above query.

```
scope :public_service_templates,                  ->         { where(miq_user_roles: { settings: nil }) }
```

Schema of tables:

```
Schema of `miq_groups table:

  create_table "miq_groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.string "group_type"
    t.integer "sequence"
    t.datetime "created_on"
    t.datetime "updated_on"
    t.text "settings"
    t.bigint "tenant_id"
    t.string "detailed_description"
  end

Schema of `entitlements table:

  create_table "entitlements", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "miq_group_id"
    t.bigint "miq_user_role_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "filters"
    t.text "filter_expression"
    t.index ["miq_group_id"], name: "index_entitlements_on_miq_group_id"
  end


Schema of miq_uer_roles table:

  create_table "miq_user_roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.boolean "read_only"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "settings"
  end

Schema of service_templates table:

  create_table "service_templates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
    t.string "guid"
    t.string "type"
    t.bigint "service_template_id"
    t.text "options"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "display"
    t.bigint "evm_owner_id"
    t.bigint "miq_group_id"
    t.string "service_type"
    t.string "prov_type"
    t.float "provision_cost"
    t.bigint "service_template_catalog_id"
    t.text "long_description"
    t.bigint "tenant_id"
    t.string "generic_subtype"
    t.datetime "deleted_on"
    t.boolean "internal"
    t.bigint "zone_id"
    t.bigint "currency_id"
    t.float "price"
    t.index ["currency_id"], name: "index_service_templates_on_currency_id"
    t.index ["generic_subtype"], name: "index_service_templates_on_generic_subtype"
    t.index ["type"], name: "index_service_templates_on_type"
  end
```

Model definition of `service_templates`.

```
class ServiceTemplate < ApplicationRecord
  include SupportsFeatureMixin

  DEFAULT_PROCESS_DELAY_BETWEEN_GROUPS = 120

  GENERIC_ITEM_SUBTYPES = {
    "custom"          => N_("Custom"),
    "vm"              => N_("Virtual Machine"),
    "playbook"        => N_("Playbook"),
    "hosted_database" => N_("Hosted Database"),
    "load_balancer"   => N_("Load Balancer"),
    "storage"         => N_("Storage")
  }.freeze

  SERVICE_TYPE_ATOMIC    = 'atomic'.freeze
  SERVICE_TYPE_COMPOSITE = 'composite'.freeze

  RESOURCE_ACTION_UPDATE_ATTRS = [:dialog,
                                  :dialog_id,
                                  :fqname,
                                  :configuration_template,
                                  :configuration_template_id,
                                  :configuration_template_type].freeze

  include CustomActionsMixin
  include ServiceMixin
  include OwnershipMixin
  include NewWithTypeStiMixin
  include TenancyMixin
  include ArchivedMixin
  include CiFeatureMixin
  include_concern 'Filter'
  include_concern 'Copy'


  validates :name, :presence => true
  belongs_to :tenant

  has_many   :service_templates, :through => :service_resources, :source => :resource, :source_type => 'ServiceTemplate'
  has_many   :services


  has_many :service_template_tenants, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :additional_tenants, :through => :service_template_tenants, :source => :tenant, :dependent => :destroy

  has_one :picture, :dependent => :destroy, :as => :resource, :autosave => true

  belongs_to :service_template_catalog
  belongs_to :zone
  belongs_to :currency, :inverse_of => false

  has_many   :dialogs, -> { distinct }, :through => :resource_actions
  has_many   :miq_schedules, :as => :resource, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many   :miq_requests, :as => :source, :dependent => :nullify
  has_many   :active_requests, -> { where(:request_state => MiqRequest::ACTIVE_STATES) }, :as => :source, :class_name => "MiqRequest"
  ...
end
```

Comment: This looks like a very overcomplicated and inefficient solution. You should just define an indirect assocation so that you can do a left join and set a condition on the joined table - `ServiceTemplate.joins(:miq_user_roles).where(miq_user_roles: { settings: nil })`.

Comment: No I can't do that. I get the following error..

`Can't join 'ServiceTemplate' to association named 'miq_user_roles'; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: Also serivceTempalte doesn't have a foreign key for miq_user_roles. servicetemplate has miq_group_id and entitlements have miq_group_id and miq_user_role_id.

Comment: Thats why I said define the indirect assocations. The code here has way to much irrelevant junk for anyone to really want to slog through. If you want answers you need to trim this way down to the stuff thats actually relevant to this problem.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to define indirect association for this? I'll trim down the question

Comment: I did not read the question and there are definitely better ways but reading the Subject and the first code block you can accomplish this as follows: `ServiceTemplate.where(miq_group_id: Entitlement.select(:miq_group_id).where(miq_user_role_id: MiqUserRole.where(settings: nil)))`

Comment: @engineersmnky I'll test that. But do you know how I can write `has_many` or `belongs_to` for this so I can query easily?

Comment: are you asking about `has_many :miq_groups; has_many :entitlements, through: :miq_groups; has_many :miq_user_roles, through: :entitlements` ?

Comment: @engineersmnky seems like primary_key_issue. I've added the schema in the question. Can you verify that and correct the `has_many`. Here is the error I'm getting

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column miq_groups.service_template_id does not exist LINE 1: ...OM "service_templates" INNER JOIN "miq_groups" ON "miq_group... ^ [catalog/explorer]`

Comment: Sorry change `has_many :miq_groups` to `belongs_to :miq_group`

Comment: @engineersmnky that doesn't work. I get the following error `undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass [catalog/explorer]`.